# Re-open tab in salesforce console app

Tags: lightning, aura, console

I want to create function for reopening(refreshing) component or whole opened tab by clicking on the button.

I couldnt find any working example. I am using aura lightning component.

cmp:

```
<lightning:button label="Storno" onclick="{!c.storno}" aura:id="new-trans-button"/>
```

controller:

```
storno : function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var subtabId = 'scc-st-0';
        sforce.console.refreshSubtabById(subtabId, true, refreshSuccess);
```

I used something like this, but i dont know how to get subtabId and i am getting error

```
sforce is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the console API via the [lightning:workspaceAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation) component. This has methods such as `refreshTab` that:

> Refreshes a workspace tab or a subtab specified by tabId. Keep in mind
>   that the first subtab has the same tabId as the workspace tab.

This component provides a "service" rather than rendering UI directly. Include it on your component and find it by its `aura:id` and invoke its methods.

Note that [Promises](https://javascript.info/promise-basics) are used in many methods to allow asynchronous completion.

Answer (score 0):

you should use RefreshTab() method from lightning:Worksapce API.

PFB the sample Code:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>
    <lightning:button label="Refresh Focused Tab" onclick="{!c.refreshFocusedTab}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Js Code

```
    ({
    refreshFocusedTab : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            workspaceAPI.refreshTab({
                      tabId: focusedTabId,
                      includeAllSubtabs: true
             });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
})
```

for More info visit this link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_refreshTab.htm

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce classic Shift+C opens the recently closed tabs. In Lightning, you can go Your console->Customize Keyboard Shortcuts and set there.